# Updating Fill Color on Visibility Change Trigger

Tags: wpf, triggers, visibility

I need to change the Color of the Rectangle in DataGrid based on the order of Visibility. For example, if I have 5 rows, and if rectangle of 3rd row becomes visible for the first time it should be filled green. Next visible rectangle should be red, and then so on...

Here is my code:

```
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="colorBox" Height="15" Width="15"  Stroke="#9C9C9C" 
                                           Visibility="{Binding Path=IsDisplayable, 
                                                                Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}}">
                            <Rectangle.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding Path=FillColor}" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Rectangle.Style>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

I have written this code, but its not working. Logically, there seems to be no mistake but actually I think this trigger is never get called when visibility of rectangle changes.
Please suggest me a good solution to this problem. Thanks

The IsDisplayable property is updated here:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="CheckboxColumnHeader" 
                                Header="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=treeView}, Path=DataContext.CheckboxColumnHeader}"
                                IsReadOnly="True" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="displayedObjects" IsChecked="{Binding IsDisplayable, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        </CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And finally, here is code behind:

```
public bool IsDisplayable
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isDisplayable;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.isDisplayable!= value)
            {
                this.isDisplayable= value;
                //NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.isDisplayable);
                Action notify = () => NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.isDisplayable);
                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, notify);
            }
        }
    }

    public Brush FillColor
    {
        get
        {
            return signalColors[currentColorIndex];
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is your row's datacontext defined? What's your code behind? More context please.

Answer (score 0):

You can completely get rid of you trigger...

```
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle x:Name="colorBox" Height="15" width="15"
                           Fill="{Binding Path=FillColor}"
                           Visibility="{Binding Path=IsDisplayable, 
                                 Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}}"
                 />
             </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Assuming that `FillColor` property is of the type `Brush` and not `Color`! If it is a `Color` type then apply `ColorToBrushConverter` ...

This is found in **Extended Toolkit** on [CodePlex](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CGAQFjAA&url=http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/&ei=pmoiUPCDB82rrAfP64G4AQ&usg=AFQjCNG8evhUk2o_B6fUUxRSuHf5AQdYAQ&sig2=UktbdT2GyxVdAo6IRVLytw)...

```
    <Window .... 
          xmlns:Toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Core.Converters; assembly=WPFToolkit.Extended"
          ...>
          <DataGrid ...>
               ....

               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate.Resources>
                          <Toolkit:ColorToSolidColorBrushConverter 
                             x:Key="colorToSolidBrushConverter" /> 
                     <DataTemplate.Resources> 
                     <Rectangle x:Name="colorBox" Height="15" width="15"
                           Fill="{Binding Path=FillColor, 
                                Converter={StaticResource colorToSolidBrushConverter}}"
                           Visibility="{Binding Path=IsDisplayable, 
                                 Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}}"
                      />
                 </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                ....
          </DataGrid>
   </Window>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. More background information is .. for example if a rectangle is first one to become visible, it should be green, the second visible rectangle should be red... so if a rectangle becomes collapsed, the visible rectangles should be colored accordingly... thats why i needed to have a trigger.